# GWT's @JsType - what do I need to play with it?

Tags: java, gwt

I have read about the new way to interoperate with native JavaScript objects in GWT applications - the way which uses interfaces annotated with @JsType:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tir74SB-ZWrs-gQ8w-lOEV3oMY6u6lF2MmNivDEihZ4/edit#heading=h.7w4qj58w18ep

However, on GWT's official website I couldn't find any information about that.

Is there any reliable source about this feature?

In what GWT's version will this feature work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reliable source about this feature?

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS1wxINeBWjeGYxbkJpamxFZ28/edit

also it's enabled over flag: -XjsInteropMode JS

> In what GWT's version will this feature work?

gwt-2.7.0

example:
https://github.com/cdigiano/polymergwt